# How to add image on my <ul> <li> tab in my case?

Tags: html, css

I have done a simple tab layout by using **html** `<ul><li>` with some **CSS**, [my code example is here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/9/) .
HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.sizzledcore.com/wp-content/themes/SizzledCore-7.0/images/facebook.png" alt="Icon" /></image></br>One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li{
   float: left;
}

a{

  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #003300;

  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none; 

}

a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #990000;
}
```

After you looked at my code, you saw I tried to have a image on top of the text on each tab, in my current code, I only did it on the first tab, but it looks urgly, so, I start to doubt am I using a good way to do it? Could some one give some suggestions on the correct way to **have a image above tab text** as each tab's content based on my code ?

**P.S.** What I mean **urgly**  on my current implementation is that there is a big gap between image and text on the tab.

Comment: what do you need anyway? maybe you can attach the image into the li background.

Comment: @ bitsMix, thank u for you response, actually I do not know what I need to do, that's why I post my question here, as I am a newbie in CSS, I tried something but not sure am I right or not. I am seeking for a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer that solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/13/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #003300;
}

li:hover
{
    background-color: #990000;
}

a
{         
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 35px 32px 7px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.facebook
{
    background-image: url('http://www.sizzledcore.com/wp-content/themes/SizzledCore-7.0/images/facebook.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 10px;
}
```

Comment: hey! looks much better than my implementation. Thank you! I learnt.

Comment: By the way, if I want to change the image for the selected tab, I thought it should be done with javascript. But is there any css trick can also be used for this purpose?? And how about change image when mouse hover the tab?

Comment: And I also notice a problem that if <a> element has also a background image, the <li> background image will be hided, how to get rid of this then?

Answer (score 0):

```
    li{
   float: left;


}

a{ 
  width:60px; 

  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #003300;

  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;

  text-align:center;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #990000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted like this?

I just made a quick example

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq7LC/18/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class='face'>One</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
li{
   float: left;
}

li a {

  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #003300;

  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-decoration: none; 

}

a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #990000;
}

.face {
        background: url("http://www.sizzledcore.com/wp-content/themes/SizzledCore-7.0/images/facebook.png") no-repeat 0px -3px;
    display: block;
}
```

(updated your code)